# angular how to await subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am newbie regarding Angular applications. I don't understand exactly how `subscribe` works. My current blocker is that I don't understand why the `console.log("B")` is executed before the `console.log("A")`, consequently presenting the result of an empty array (see the links to `console` output).

I tried to put all the code in a function with `async/await` to wait for the function.  I don't understand why it doesn't work.

What is the best way in this case to wait for a subscription?

The `console.log("B")` must be executed after the `console.log("A")`.

```
this._roleService.getRoleTypes(this.token).subscribe(
    response => {
        if(response.status != "error" && response.code != 400){
            let _roleTypes:Array<RoleType> = new Array<RoleType>(); 
            _roleTypes = new Array<RoleType>();
            response.data.forEach(rt => {
                let roleType:RoleType = new RoleType(
                    rt.id,
                    rt.name
                );
                _roleTypes.push(roleType);
            });
            console.log("A");
            console.log(_roleTypes);
            this.roleTypes = _roleTypes;
        }
        else{
            this._loginService.destroySession();
        }
    },error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        if(this.errorMessage != null){
            console.log(this.errorMessage);
            alert("Petition Error");
        }
    }
);
console.log("B");
console.log(this.roleTypes);
```

- [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4vaU.png)
- [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSVIQ.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may know, subscriptions are used to handle async method call. Thus, the code inside the subscribe() method is executed only when the async method return its result (after a http call for instance).

While waiting for the async response, the program continues and execute the following code. That's the goal of async calls!

That's why your `console.log('B')` is executed before your `console.log('A')`.

Here is an example:

```
this.myservice.asyncCall().subscribe( (result) => {
   // wait for the async response
   console.log('I get some data from asyncCall()');
});
// sync code executed, even if the previous async call doesn't respond anything
console.log('Code executed after the subscription. But not waiting for it to respond');
```

If you want you're `console.log('B')`, you have to move it into your subscription function (after the else statement). You can also call a method from that location, depending on the purpose you're looking for.

You may take a look at the [`.map()`](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/map.html) method as well. This allows you to edit the retrieved response before you handle it in the subscribe method (to add it some data, transform it, log or anything).

Comment: sorry..and what is the best way to do multiple non async operations?

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiple non async operations'? Every single code line is a non async operation. Only some methods needing a "subscribe" at the end are async.

Comment: Is it possible to use await?

Comment: Await are meant to simulate a synchrone behavior over an asynchrone method. Your code will wait for the completion of the promise before going to the next line. So that's not the same purpose here! But yes, es6 await/async can be used with angular 2+ promises.On angularjs, have a look to $q.

Answer (score 56):

you can achieve this using the `firstValueFrom` method. It is also a great way to handle asynchronous operations. Just remove the subscribe and add this method and add the async keyword in the method from where you are calling this method.

Example-

```
 const response = await firstValueFrom(this._roleService.getRoleTypes(this.token));
```

So, Now you will get console.log("A") first then console.log("B").

UPDATE: `firstValueFrom` is only available from RxJS v7 onwards. If you are using RxJS v6 or less, you will need to use `.ToPromise()`. So:

```
 const response = await this._roleService.getRoleTypes(this.token).ToPromise();
```

Comment: That's a great answer. I would cast double vote to that. I am surprised no one marked it as an answer. This absolutely awaits a subscribe.

Comment: Strange but it's not working for me :(

Comment: Worked with `"@angular/core": "13.3.0"` and  `"rxjs": "7.4.0"`

Answer (score 30):

You should use async/await if you need synchronous execution of your code. Wrap your subscribe code in a function that returns a promise.

```
async getRolestypes(): Promise<Array<RoleType>> {

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     this._roleService.getRoleTypes(this.token).subscribe(
       response => {
         if(response.status != "error" && response.code != 400){
          let _roleTypes:Array<RoleType> = new Array<RoleType>(); 
          _roleTypes = new Array<RoleType>();
          response.data.forEach(rt => {
            let roleType:RoleType = new RoleType(
                rt.id,
                rt.name
            );
            _roleTypes.push(roleType);
           });
          console.log("A");
          console.log(_roleTypes);
          resolve(_roleTypes);
       }
       else{
           this._loginService.destroySession();
           reject('not a good response')
       }
       },error => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        if(this.errorMessage != null){
           reject(this.errorMessage);
        }
      }
    );


  })


}


this.roleTypes = await getRolestypes();
console.log(this.roleTypes);
```

Answer (score 5):

@sunny answer above is my preferred choice. But `toPromise` has been deprecated in RxJs 7 and won't probably be there
when RxJs 8 is released. So the new way would be:

```js
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

const roleTypes$ = this._roleService.getRoleTypes(this.token);
const response = await lastValueFrom(roleTypes$);
```

Answer (score -1):

subscribe is executed asynchronously. In your case, subscribe will execute and then console.log('B') will get executed after that. When at a later point of time, the Observable posts the response (based on success/error), corresponding success/error callback will be invoked. so you can handle console.log('B') in in the success callback