# Getting 'Cannot read property of undefined' when accessing an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have this object defined based on the elements that I retrieved from my HTTP request. The problem is that I'm trying to access these elements in the Object Array, I'm getting this 'Cannot read property of undefined' error. Can you please advise where do I go wrong? Because I think I'm accessing it the right way.
[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A78Jc.png)

**app.module.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  public blockchain;

  constructor(private blockchainService: BlockchainService) {
    this.blockchain = blockchainService.blockchainInstance;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ...
}
```

**Object class**

```
export class BlockchainDB {
  id?: any;
  provider?: string;
  recipient?: string;
  rxInfo?: string;
  timestamp?: string;
  published?: boolean;
}
```

**Code**

```
export class BlockchainService {

  ...
  currentBlockchain: BlockchainDB = {
    rxInfo: '',
    provider: '',
    recipient: '',
    timestamp: '',
    published: false
  };
  ...
  public sampledata = [];
  public arraydata3: BlockchainDB [];

  constructor(private blockchainService: BlockchainDBService) {
    this.retrieveBlockchain();
    this.createChainData();

    console.log(this.arraydata3);
    console.log(this.arraydata3[0].rxInfo);
  }

createChainData() {
    this.getBlockchain('1', 0);
    this.getBlockchain('2', 1);
   }

  getBlockchain(id: string, seqnr: number): void {
    console.log(id);
    this.blockchainService.get(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.currentBlockchain = data;
          this.arraydata3.push(this.currentBlockchain);
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
   }
```

**Debug Logs**

```
1
blockchain.service.ts:78 2
blockchain.service.ts:50 Array(2)0: {id: 1, provider: "steve", recipient: "me", rxInfo: "{brandname:neozep,genericname:paracetamol,prescribedDosageCount:20}", timestamp: "1630747314781", …}1: {id: 2, provider: "qwerty", recipient: "trewq", rxInfo: "{brandname:biogesic,genericname:paracetamol,prescribedDosageCount:20}", timestamp: "1730747314781", …}length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
core.js:6479 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'rxInfo' of undefined
    at new BlockchainService (blockchain.service.ts:51)
    at Object.BlockchainService_Factory [as factory] (blockchain.service.ts:122)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11438)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25332)`enter code here`
    at Object.get (core.js:25046)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14737)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:9)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6479
main.ts:12 TypeError: Cannot read property 'rxInfo' of undefined
    at new BlockchainService (blockchain.service.ts:51)
    at Object.BlockchainService_Factory [as factory] (blockchain.service.ts:122)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11438)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25332)
    at Object.get (core.js:25046)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14737)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (app.component.ts:9)
```

Comment: How are you instantiating `BlockchainService`? Also looks like `getBlockChain` has some asynchronous logic and you are calling `console.log(this.arraydata3[0].rxInfo)` before that finishes.

Comment: Hi morgan, what i do here is that i retrieve the data from an api i created on my side. the weird thing is that, in my code console.log(this.arraydata3); is not showing an error. but  console.log(this.arraydata3[0].rxInfo); is showing an error. That's why i'm thinking, data should already be available when im calling the rxinfo. Since before that, I already outputted the whole data.

Comment: And what was shown in the console when you printed the whole data? Your example doesn't show the code for `retrieveBlockchain` either. I'm suggesting that your console statement is happening before the actual data is set. What is `this.blockchainService`?

Comment: In the `subscribe` callback change `console.log(data);` to `console.log(this.arraydata3[0].rxInfo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the subscription is executed when the api call is completed which is asynchronous.

Therefore, "**console.log(this.arraydata3[0].rxInfo);**" is executed before "**this.arraydata3.push(this.currentBlockchain);**"

You can handle this asynchronous behvior by following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185502/angular-how-to-await-subscribe/48185851)

Comment: As mentioned by morgan and safir, this was due to asynchronous behaviour. I had to change some logic in my code. Thanks,